# How to specify order of a categorical variable in highcharts using R?

Tags: r, shiny, highcharts

I have created a factor variable in R using:

`dat$Response <- ifelse((dat$questions2 ==  "Q1" | dat$questions2 ==  "Q8" | dat$questions2 ==  "Q9" | dat$questions2 ==  "Q11"), factor(dat$Response, c("Strongly agree","Agree","Don't know","Disagree","Strongly disagree")),dat$Response)`

Essentially, if the question is one of those specified, then I want to factor the responses as according to the code. This seems to work.
However, using the highcharts library in a shiny apps environment, when I use the response variable for grouping (i.e. it appears in the legend of the chart), I only get numbers. That is, the responses appear as: 1,2,3,4,5 rather than: "Strongly agree","Agree","Don't know","Disagree","Strongly disagree" in the chart's legend.
Does anyone know what needs to be changed? Do I need to add something to my code when I specify the server side of the shiny app?

I have searched the internet high and low for an answer and am really stuck.

Comment: Please post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want someone to help you.  Do include some sample data.